# How could I load the default home page in Qt WebView?

Tags: qt, webkit, webview

I have a button for my web browser using Qt Designer, but I need to assign a slot that will load the default webpage.
I have tried:

```
ui->webView->load(ui->webView->url());
```

But, it would have the same effect as reload. Any help is appreciated?

By the way, this is not a homework, but a home project that is being done for fun.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "default webpage", but what you need to do is, e.g.

```
ui->webView->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
```

substitute "http://www.google.com" with the web page you want to load.

For a QWebView defined in Qt designer where you specified an url, it will be loaded when you instantiate the form, you don't need to load it yourself via a slot.

Comment: I understand that you can load a web url that way. In designer, there is a option to type in the default url for a webview display widget in the "property" panel on the right side of designer.

Comment: The problem I am is loading that "default" url. :)

Comment: Hmm ok that makes sense. Is there a way to load that page, (ie) if my home page(lol it just clicked that it was called home) is http://www.google.com/ but I am currently on YouTube and would like to go back to my home. what function should I look into in Qt's API/Documentation?

Comment: The url you set in Designer is not a "Home page", but an initial page. To go back to it from an arbitrary page, you'll have to "load" it manually. To implement "Back" functionality, there are builtin QAction's, e.g. QWebPage::action(QWebPage::Back). You have to connect or directly call the action's "trigger()" slot to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

To reload a web page, use this piece of code.

```
page->triggerAction(QWebPage::Reload);
```

or

```
page->triggerAction(QWebPage::ReloadAndBypassCache);
```